# Is it possible that the Universe is expanding due to additional Big Bang events?

Tags: universe, astrophysics, cosmology, big-bang-theory

Is it theoretically possible that the Universe is expanding due to additional Big Bang events that have occurred at the same location that the original Big Bang occurred at?

Perhaps there has been an ongoing series of smaller Big Bang events over the past 13.7 billion years, which although were not as massive in scale as the original Big Bang, have created a large amount of new space-time and new matter that has resulted in the Universe expanding.

Comment: One problem with this argument is that the expansion appears highly uniform.   Different "big bangs" would suggest a lack of uniformity, where as one, that happened everywhere, implies high uniformity and that's what we observe.

Comment: Suggest you read [Did the Big Bang happen at a point ?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/136860/did-the-big-bang-happen-at-a-point#136861) on the Physics SE site.

Comment: @userLTK There were (are) ideas that maybe the Higgs field may have a different value in the for us unreachable regions of the Universe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need to revisit the theory behind the [Big Bang](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Bang). The Big Bang is more or less a description of what the early universe looks like if you view expansion in reverse. The single "Big Bang" at the beginning of our universe is the only "Big Bang" event predicted by expansion. Also, the Big Bang did not happen in a single place, it happened everywhere in the universe. Finally, the Big Bang did not create space-time, and the expansion of the universe is not the creation of new matter. The Big Bang describes a time when the metric of space-time was extremely dense, and expansion is the metric of space-time increasing as below:

[image: Expansion of space]

The distance between points in space increases, but the same mass-energy is there as before.